# How i can pass value vue to hidden textbox

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

i need to pass value from vue to textbox, doing for one day but still didn't work.

my html input type code

```
<input type="hidden" id="variation" name="variation" v-model="variation">
```

second is my is my value is appear on paragraph

```
<p name fs="paragraph" fw="semi-bold" color="dark">{{ getVariantTitle(variant) }}</p>
```

its works for passing value to paragraph but not working for passing value into hidden html textbox. i really need value for passing into form post.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is better way to achieve what you're trying to do but for a quick fix you can try using `v-bind` instead of `v-model`

`<input type="hidden" id="variation" name="variation" v-bind:value="variation">`

This means the `hidden` text field will always have the same value as `this.variation`

EDIT:

`<input type="hidden" id="variation" name="variation" :value="getVariantTitle(variant)">`

Comment: i see it but it still not working. how to pass `{{ getVariantTitle(variant) }}` like on paragraph to input hidden value?

Comment: i have updated my answer. The two values will now be in sync.

Comment: yeah its working now. you just saved my day. thanks

Comment: you seem new to stack overflow. you can upvote and mark this answer as accepted if it helped you solve the issue. it also saves time for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

As the input type is hidden, instead of v-model just try using v-bind:value, as you don't need two way binding for a hidden input

Comment: after i use v-bind, value going to return to another input. but if use :value , value is return will be `object+HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: the :value is same as v-bind:value, as : is shorthand for v-bind. Did you mean v-model in your comment?

Comment: no. i mean :value. i dont know why value return to `object+HTMLInputElement`

Comment: its working now by using value. i just put wrong formatted in value that why is not working before that. thanks